# Using bread to return a bstring

Tags: c, file-io

- gcc 4.7.2
- c89
- `bstrlib.h` from [Better String Library](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/)

I am maintaining someone's code that looks like this:

```
FILE *db_fp = NULL;
bstring data = NULL;

db_fp = db_open(DB_FILE, "r");
LOG_CHECK(db_fp == NULL, "Failed to open database: %s", DB_FILE);

data = bread((bNread)fread, db_fp);
LOG_CHECK(data == NULL, "Failed to read from db file: %s", DB_FILE);

db_close(db_fp);

return data;
```

I am having a little trouble understanding the following line:

```
data = bread((bNread)fread, db_fp);
```

What I can guess, is that it is fetching a bstream from the following file pointer and returning a bstring. However, I am wondering about bread and fread.

bread contains 2 arguments, A function pointer (bNread) and the file pointer. But I am not sure I understand how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration for `bread()` in the Better String Library documentation is:

```
typedef size_t (*bNread)(void *buff, size_t elsize, size_t nelem, void *parm);
extern bstring bread(bNread readPtr, void *parm);
```

Therefore, `bread()` is a function that takes a pointer to a function as an argument.  The `bNread` type is used to specify the type of function.  The `fread()` function is close enough to pass muster when cast — the match isn't exact because it expects a `FILE *` for its fourth argument and a true function of the type pointed at by a `bNread` expects a `void *`.  The second argument to `bread` is the value to be passed as the fourth argument to the function pointed to by the `bNread`.

So, in the code you're maintaining:

```
data = bread((bNread)fread, db_fp);
```

The Better String Library function is called with `fread()` as the I/O function, cast to the correct type to quell an otherwise justified compiler warning about a mismatch in types, plus the file stream that should be used for reading.

---

The implementation of the `bread()` function uses the function pointer and the stream pointer whenever it needs to do I/O in order to read a string.  That is, as KerrekB also explained, the code
might write something like:

```
char buffer[256];

size_t nbytes = (*readPtr)(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), parm);
```

or (equivalently):

```
size_t nbytes = readPtr(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), parm);
```

(If you learned C long enough ago, the first was the only way to invoke functions through pointers to functions; since the C89 standard was produced, the second has been available and is probably used more widely these days.)  There are a number of tricks that the implementation must worry about, but the basic function call would be somewhat similar.  The code could use I/O functions other than `fread()`, though the interface to the function must be similar.

Pointers to functions are powerful, but are arcane until you've used them.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible implementation of `bread`:

```
bstring bread(int(*func)(void *, size_t, size_t ,FILE *), FILE * fp)
{
    char buf[10];
    bstring result;

    func(buf, 10, 1, fp);
    return result;
}
```

This doesn't of course reflect what the *real* function `bread` is doing, but it should give you an idea how an implementation might use it.

(The real function would of course read a length from `fp` first, then allocate enough memory for the string, and then read the string, but the details depend on what `bstring` is and how it works. A real implementation would also check the return value of `func`!)